# How to extract inline CSS from React UI components generated by Amplify from synced Figma?

Tags: css, reactjs, aws-amplify, figma

I am using Amplify to generate React UI components from a synced Figma file, but I've noticed that the generated components have inline CSS styles instead of using a dedicated CSS file or a CSS module implementation. There's too much CSS inline and the pages are super big.

I have searched for documentation or guidelines on how to extract the inline CSS and place it in a separate CSS file or use CSS modules, but I haven't been able to find any relevant information.

Can someone please guide me on how to extract the inline CSS styles from these React UI components and organize them in a more maintainable and reusable way? Specifically, I would like to know:

How to separate the inline CSS styles from the React UI components.

Any assistance or pointers to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!